# Linq to SQL Date conversion error

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to filter a Linq to SQL query on an optional date field and I am having a problem. Here is the method:

```
public List<ReferralTrackerModel> GetDoctorDailySchedule(int DBID, int DoctorCode, string apptDateFrom, string apptDateTo)
    {
        using (var dbIMEC = getISSDataContext(DBID))
        {
            var eResults = from c in dbIMEC.tblCases
                           join s in dbIMEC.tblServices on c.ServiceCode equals s.ServiceCode
                           join e in dbIMEC.tblExaminees on c.ChartNbr equals e.ChartNbr
                           join p in dbIMEC.tblPublishOnWebs on c.CaseNbr equals p.TableKey
                           join ct in dbIMEC.tblCaseTypes on c.CaseType equals ct.Code
                           join l in dbIMEC.tblLocations on c.DoctorLocation equals l.LocationCode.ToString()
                           where p.UserCode == DoctorCode
                           where p.TableType == "tblCase"
                           where p.PublishOnWeb
                           where p.TableKey == c.CaseNbr
                           where p.UserType == "DR"
                           //where c.ApptDate >= DateTime.Parse(apptDateFrom)
                           //where c.ApptDate <= DateTime.Parse(apptDateFrom).Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59)
                           select new ReferralTrackerModel()
                           {
                               CaseNbr = c.CaseNbr,
                               ClaimNbr = c.ClaimNbr.Trim(),
                               ExamLocationName = l.Location.Trim(),
                               ExamineeName = e.LastName.Trim() + ", " + e.FirstName.Trim(),
                               CaseType = ct.Description.Trim(),
                               ServiceDesc = s.Description.Trim(),
                               ApptDateTime = c.ApptTime.ToString().Trim(),
                               ApptDateTimeDate = DateTime.Parse(c.ApptTime.ToString())
                           };

            if (apptDateTo.Length > 0)
            {
                var dateTo = DateTime.Parse(apptDateTo);
                eResults = eResults.Where(r => r.ApptDateTimeDate <= dateTo);
            }

            var lst = eResults.ToList();

            return lst;
        }
    }

      The date calculation in the main part of the query is working as expected but the portion after the if statement is not. I am getting the following error back from the API controller:
```

"message": "Method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."

My intention is to filter the results by the optional apptDateTo field when it is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LINQ expression, and anything that gets added to the expression tree before it's materialized into memory, has to be translatable into a query for the backing data store.  In this case, SQL.  And SQL indeed has no translation for `DateTime.Parse()`.

Parse the value first, entirely in C# code and unrelated to the LINQ query, then use the result to query the data:

```
if (apptDateTo.Length > 0)
{
    var dateTo = DateTime.Parse(apptDateTo);
    eResults = eResults.Where(r => r.ApptDateTimeDate <= dateTo);
}
```

**Edit:** I notice that you're also using `DateTime.Parse()` in several other places throughout your LINQ code.  For example:

```
where c.ApptDate >= DateTime.Parse(apptDateFrom)
```

The same principle applies there as well.  You can't use operations not supported by the backing data store in LINQ.  Parse the value first, then use it in the query.

Comment: I tried that earlier and I still get the same error. I tried your code and I still get the error. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: @CrystalLake62: I just updated the answer.  It looks like you have *several* uses of `DateTime.Parse()` throughout your LINQ code.  The same solution applies and would need to be applied anywhere you use it.

Comment: The odd thing is the upper part of the query works as desired even with the datetime conversion. Still having trouble with the conditional part.

Comment: @CrystalLake62: Define "works as desired".  All most of this code does is define a query.  I wouldn't expect the error to occur until you try to execute the query, which is later in the code.  You simply need to remove all uses of `DateTime.Parse()` (as well as anything else which produces a similar error, of course) from your LINQ code.

Comment: I commented out the conversions on the main query just in case and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What I mean is the query works without the conditional if, even with the date conversions here:                                where c.ApptDate >= DateTime.Parse(apptDateFrom)
                               where c.ApptDate <= DateTime.Parse(apptDateFrom).Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59)

Comment: @CrystalLake62: What's the updated code?  You can edit it into the question.  If you're still getting the error then it seems you missed one.

Comment: I added the edited code, still getting the same error.

Comment: @CrystalLake62: Well, you haven't addressed any of the other instances of `DateTime.Parse` in the LINQ query.  That was what I added to this answer after your first comment about still seeing the error.  Do a "find" of the string "DateTime.Parse" in your code, it's in *several* places.  You need to correct *all* of them.

Comment: I commented out the DateTime.Parse in the top portion as you suggested and left in the code in the if statement. I am still getting the same error. I posted the edited code for your reference. When I take out the if statement completely all works fine even WITH the DateTime.Parse stuff in the top portion. I get what you are saying that sql doesn't know what that is though.

Comment: @CrystalLake62: Which line throws the error?  If you're no longer *using* `DateTime.Parse()` then it wouldn't make sense that an error is complaining about it.  At that point I'd suspect that there's a mistake in the debugging somewhere, such as using an old version of the build or the error coming from somewhere else.

Comment: The error is coming from the code inside of the if statement. When I remove it, everything works fine but of course the todate is not part of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Store the results of `DateTime.Parse` to a variable and use that.

```
        if (apptDateTo.Length > 0)
        {
            var parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(apptDateTo);
            eResults = eResults.Where(r => r.ApptDateTimeDate <= parsedDate);
        }
```

The problem is that LINQ to SQL is trying to turn the `DateTime.Parse` call into something in SQL and it doesn't know how to do that.  This stops LINQ to SQL from trying.

Comment: It's because in the select part of your query you define `ApptDateTimeDate` as `DateTime.Parse(c.ApptTime.ToString())`. So in that optional where clause, it is substituting the parse call for that field.  And that loops back to `DateTime.Parse` not having an appropriate conversion to SQL, thus the error you are getting. Is `ApptTime` a string in your database or some other type? If it is a string, you are kinda screwed, you'll have to either ditch LINQ to SQL for this one and use handwritten SQL or bring all the data back first then filter with the date.  If it's a date, just use that instead.